# Date Column Sorting not working for data table grid if any of the row contains empty date

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

I am using data table plugin and I need to get date column sorted in ascending/descending when clicked on the date column's header. But if any of the row contains empty date then sorting of that date column does not work properly. If all rows contain date then sorting works correctly. Kindly suggest me an answer.

I already installed jquery data table plugin and provided the jquery code for sorting as below.

```
  this.CreateDataTable = function () {
        $("#dtTable").DataTable({          
            lengthChange: false,          
            searching: false,
            "order": [
                [1, 'asc']
            ],
            "columnDefs": [                      
                { "orderable": false, type: 'date-dd-mmm-yyyy' }               
            ],
            "aoColumns": [null, {
                'iDataSort': 2
            }, {
                "bVisible": false
            }]
        });
    };
```

Below shows screenshot of error:
[image]

Comment: so if a row has an empty date and your sort `asc`, where would you expect the empty 'date row's' position be?  top or bottom?

Comment: I expect the empty date row's position to be at the top when sorted in ascending order when sorted in descending order I expect them to be at the bottom.